# Trying to number objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to number objects, which can be added to a cart with drag'n'drop. So, this snippet should check the current number written in `span.amountVal`, and easily add ´+1´ to this number, but the result is always ´1´. When I uncomment the ´alert(i++);´, the snippet work like I want to. I'm confused, what is this about?

```
$.favList.find("div[data-asset-id="+ _itemID +"]").each(function() {
    var i = $(this).find("span.amountVal").text();

    // alert(i++);

    $(this).find("span.amountVal").text(i++);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i++` first returns the value of `i`, *then* increments it. When you have the `alert( i++ )` in place, the variable is already once incremented.

Put the `++` in front of the variable:

```
$(this).find("span.amountVal").text( ++i );
```

Or simply add one to it since you're discarding the variable right after:

```
$(this).find("span.amountVal").text( i + 1 );
```

Comment: the `++i` thing did it, thank you. We will never learned out :)

Answer (score 2):

you have a `pre-increment/post-increment` issue, the following change should solve it:

```
$.favList.find("div[data-asset-id="+ _itemID +"]").each(function() {
    var i = $(this).find("span.amountVal").text();

    $(this).find("span.amountVal").text(++i);
});
```

`Pre-Increment` adds one to `i` and ***then*** returns `i` while `Post-Increment` adds 1 to `i` after it has been returned.

Below is a similar post on StackOverflow touching on the topic:

[post increment vs pre increment - Javascript Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546981/post-increment-vs-pre-increment-javascript-optimization)

Answer (score 0):

What are you guys doing? It SHOULDN'T read a SPAN's value, it's bad practice. Instead, it should read the items length (inside an object, for example) and then display it.