# Stuck in an infinite for loop. What am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I have this for loop, I'm stuck in the second one, but If I am, I'd also be stuck in the first one, whats the problem here?

```
for(var i = 0; i < oldtds.length;i += 3)
{
    var oldNameIndex = sameName(oldtds[i].innerHTML, nameList);
    if(oldNameIndex != -1)
    {
        //This means the name already exists
        //I need to combine the times, and remove the tr from the table for the second name
        //this loop accesses all the times
        for(var j = i + 1; j < oldtds.length; j += 3)
        {
            //This won't quite work, There are colons between them
            var timerArray = oldtds[j].innerHTML.split(":");
            timerArray.push(oldtds[oldNameIndex + 1].innerHTML.split(":"));
            console.log(timerArray);
            console.log("this is j " + j);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is this variable's value `oldtds.length`

Comment: Assuming that `oldtds` is an array, you'd be much better off looping through it with `oldtds.forEach()`, which will allow you to not have a looping variable, which is most definitely why you have an infinite loop now.

Comment: What is sameName(), is it synchronous?

Comment: @ScottMarcus No, `.forEach` doesn't cut it when looping every third item. And even  when it did, `for … of` would be a much better solution

Comment: What exactly is `oldts`, and what exactly are you doing inside the loop body? Notice that nodelists or html collections can be live, and change their `.length` when you manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Please do some debugging. Log the values of the variables. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Bergi except they for...of isn't fully supported

Comment: Note that forEach is not as fast as a traditional for loop. May not always matter, but important to keep in mind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821759/why-array-foreach-is-slower-than-for-loop-in-javascript

Comment: data type and context are missing :-/

Comment: @SethWhite On their surface, no loop is ever going to be faster than a counting loop, simply because of the simplicity of moving sequentially via a numeric index. That, however, should not really be an issue to favor it over other looping structures.

Comment: I'm making a dynamic list that only ever has 5, I'm keeping track of them with oldtds. That part works fine, in the loop, when I log j, it stays as 1, I don't know why.