# How to add an array of values to a Set

Tags: javascript, set

The old school way of adding all values of an array into the `Set` is:

```
// for the sake of this example imagine this set was created somewhere else 
// and I cannot construct a new one out of an array
let mySet = new Set()

for(let item of array) {
  mySet.add(item)
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? Maybe `mySet.add(array)` or `mySet.add(...array)`?

PS: I know both do not work

Comment: There is a stage 1 proposal for [`Set.prototype.addAll`](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-collection-methods/#Set.prototype.add-elements)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Just a bit weird why it wasn't included in `Set#add` in the first place. Somebody must have thought `Array#push` taking multiple arguments is a bad thing.

Comment: Can't you use the set constructor? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set under Relation with Array objects.

Comment: ah , when we have arr.push(...items) why have set.add(value)  : / . I tripped on this recently. Poor API design

Answer (score 235):

While `Set` API is still very minimalistic, you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and shorten your code a bit:

```js
array.forEach(item => mySet.add(item))

// alternative, without anonymous arrow function
array.forEach(mySet.add, mySet)
```

Comment: added a version without arrow function creation

Comment: I don't think this is really any better than just a `for of` loop. The second one especially is much more confusing.

Comment: I like how *poor API* was called _minimalistic_!

Comment: Why do we need the second argument in: array.forEach(mySet.add, mySet) ?

Comment: @ed22 see [forEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): `thisArg` (optional) - value to use as `this` when executing _callback_

Comment: @amankkg so without passing thisArg, the "add" method would be executed in some other context than mySet?

Comment: @ed22 yeah, the context will be undefined

Comment: @amankkg I will never get used to the fact that mySet.add does not use the context of the object before the dot but is like a completely detached method.

Comment: @RyanShillington not true, it used to be but browsers have optimised a lot since that answer was posted. see https://jsben.ch/fxaYy (credit goes to @Redu) (originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881453/how-to-add-an-array-of-values-to-a-set#comment114865000_58996448) )

Comment: @ed22 thanks for this clarification. so even if longer in terms of characters, the syntax `array.forEach(Set.prototype.add, mySet)` looks clearer to me.

Comment: @ed22 Almost all functions do that, the only ones that don't are functions that you have already added a thisArg to using e.g. `Function::bind` or arrow functions (which inherit `this` from its parent context). This allows easy inheritance using prototypes, and allows 'borrowing' methods from other classes by assigning them as a property of an instance (or even the instance's shared prototype). Sorry for the rant.

Comment: The version without the arrow function is terrible advice. See https://jakearchibald.com/2021/function-callback-risks/
This is exactly the reason why `Set.add()` can now never be improved to take multiple parameters. The callback in `Array.forEach()` is fired with multiple arguments, so if a browser wants to ship with functionality like `mySet.add(item1, item2)` they will break existing sites.

Comment: @Jespertheend there are no user-defined functions above, otherwise one has to be cautious when using point-free style in JS

Comment: @amankkg It's true for web platform features as well. The article uses `requestAnimationFrame` as an example, but historically other functions have gained new parameters too. Either way, not using an arrow function sets a bad example and teaches people to use it in other places where it might do more harm.

Answer (score 115):

Here's a functional way, returning a new set:

```
const set = new Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
const arr = ['d', 'e', 'f']
const extendedSet = new Set([ ...set, ...arr ])
// Set { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' }
```

Comment: With this approach i end up having nested multilevel sets and arrays not a flattened set

Comment: @PauloNeves sounds like you're not using the spread syntax `...`

Comment: @PauloNeves He is copying content of the Set everytime he adds new array of item. And ofcourse use  spread syntax, "..."

Comment: This syntax is newer, but sounds like we are copy of copy of ... objects, in other words making a new set in the end and insert all elements.

Answer (score 46):

This is IMO the most elegant

```js
// for a new Set 
const x = new Set([1,2,3,4]);

// for an existing Set
const y = new Set();

x.forEach(y.add, y);
```

Comment: Another elegant one!

Comment: forEach is ~200x slower than iterating through an array. It's fine for a few values but watch out if this is something you do all the time. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43821759/491553

Comment: @RyanShillington not true, it used to be but browsers have optimised a lot since that answer was posted. see https://jsben.ch/fxaYy (credit goes to @Redu)

Comment: @WiR3D Well, holy crap. That's awesome news.

Comment: Nice and tidy, I love it!

Answer (score 17):

How about using the spread operator to easily blend your new array items into an existing set?

```
let mySet = new Set([1,2,3,4])
const additionalSet = [5,6,7,8,9]
mySet = new Set([...mySet, ...additionalSet])
```

[JSFIDDLE][1]
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/clayperez/yjkxh9d8/9/

Comment: And once more: "Obvisouly you didnt read the comment in the code where I stated that the set is created somewhere else and I cannot create a new one"

Comment: change the "const" mySet to "let"

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `Array.reduce()`:

```
const mySet = new Set();
mySet.add(42); // Just to illustrate that an existing Set is used

[1, 2, 3].reduce((s, e) => s.add(e), mySet);
```

Comment: Using `reduce` doesn't make sense here when all you need is the iteration of `forEach`. See @WiR3D's answer.

Comment: I don't really get your objection. Sometimes you want a single-statement solution, like in a lambda where you don't want a curly brace block, or in an initialization. While `reduce` may not be the most obvious choice, I fail to see how it doesn't "make sense" - you're reducing an array into something else - a Set - which is exactly what `reduce` is intended for.

Comment: I'd say you're mapping it, not reducing it here.

Comment: @JHH The point is that `[1, 2, 3].forEach(e => mySet.add(e))` or `for (const e of [1, 2, 3]) mySet.add(e)` would make more sense.

Comment: @CherryDT I think we have to agree to disagree on what making sense means. I wouldn't personally choose the reduce solution, but I added it as an option. Surprised 19 people thinks it doesn't "make sense".

Comment: @JHH that's because this is using reduce incorrectly. It shouldn't be used for side effects, that's what forEach is for.

Comment: foreach is not an expression, on the other hand reduce is, so you can both return and reduce in a single shot.

Comment: Thanks! "Reduce" faster for me in Chrome: https://jsben.ch/UmpYA

Comment: You can use most of the various Javascript iteration methods (for loops, `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, etc.) to accomplish anything that involves looping: this issue demonstrates that fact.  However, each looping approach has pros/cons to it, and often there's a clear "better option".  Unless you are highly concerned with performance, most developers (95+%) should focus on code readability/maintainability ... and `forEach` is objectively simpler, and therefore easier to read/maintain, than `reduce` (or a `for` loop ... and it's superior to `map` because `map` was designed for returning results).

Answer (score 4):

Just post that here for inspiration .. 
Creating a class that extends Set, and add a addRange method.

```js
    class MegaSet extends Set {
    
      constructor(iterable) {
       super(iterable);
      }
      
      addRange(range) {
        for (var elem of range) {
          this.add(elem);
        }
      }
    }
    
    const array = [1,2,3,5,5,6];
    let mySet = new MegaSet([1,2,3,4]);
    
    mySet.addRange(array);
    console.log([...mySet]);
```

Answer (score 4):

create a new Set:

```js
    //Existing Set
    let mySet = new Set([1,2,3,4,5]);
    //Existing Array
    let array = [6,7,8,9,0];
        
    mySet = new Set(array.concat([...mySet]));
    console.log([...mySet]);
    
    //or single line
    console.log([...new Set([6,7,8,9,0].concat([...new Set([1,2,3,4,5])]))]);
```

Comment: Is there an advantage in this combination of spread and concat? I think Julien's answer is more comprehensible.

Comment: @Robert the array already exists, in my example im creating the new set from the existing array + existing Set, Julien example he creates a new array from the other two existing object to create a fourth object thats not a good practice.

Comment: `Array#concat` also creates a new array. Your solutions express the same thing with different code, but surely it's always good to have a choice. (`array.concat([...set])` vs `[...array, ...set]`)

Answer (score 0):

Input the array in the first place, when you create the set.
You'll get the set with all items in the array.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5]
let mySet = new Set(array)
console.log(mySet)
//Add new one element
mySet.add(6)
console.log(mySet)

//Add exist element
mySet.add(6)
console.log(mySet)
```

Comment: This is not "adding an array to a Set". This is "creating a new set from an array".

Answer (score 0):

```
let mySet = new Set(['a', 'b']);
let arrayToBeAdded = ['c', 'd'];

//convert the Set to an array, then concatenate both arrays, finally convert into a Set
mySet = Array.form(mySet).concat(arrayToBeAdded);
mySet = new Set(mySet);

//in single line
mySet = new Set(Array.form(mySet).concat(arrayToBeAdded));
```

Answer (score -1):

There's currently no `addAll` method for Sets, but you have two options to simplify your life when working with them. The first one would be to extend the prototype. Before you do that, [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180) and decide afterwards if the possible consequences are ok for your project/intended use.

```
if (!Set.prototype.addAll) {
  Set.prototype.addAll = function(items) {
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) throw new TypeError('passed item is not an array');
    // or (not sure what the real Set.prototype will get sometime)
    // if (!Array.isArray(items)) items = [items];
    for (let it of items) {
      this.add(it);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

If you decided not to extend the prototype, just create a function that you can reuse in your project

```
function addAll(_set, items) {
    // check set and items
    for (let it of items) {
         _set.add(it);
    }
    return _set;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

**@Fuzzyma**, I'll suggest you to use **Prototyping** of JavaScript to define new method on **Set**.

> Do not use in-built method name defined on **Set**.
>
> If you still prefer to use the same function name as in-built function name like `add` then the better approach would be to inherit the **Set** and override `add()` method.
>
> This is better way to add methods to existing objects without affecting their methods and use our own methods with same name. The charisma of **Method overriding**, a nice OOP concept.

Here in the below code, I have defined `addItems()` on **Set**.

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/LGPQC98007.

```
var arr = [3, 7, 8, 75, 65, 32, 98, 32, 3];
var array = [100, 3, 200, 98, 65, 300]; 

// Create a Set
var mySet = new Set(arr);
console.log(mySet);

// Adding items of array to mySet
Set.prototype.addItems = function(array) {
    for(var item of array){
        this.add(item)
    }
}

mySet.addItems(array);
console.log(mySet)
```

» Output

```
Set { 3, 7, 8, 75, 65, 32, 98 }
Set { 3, 7, 8, 75, 65, 32, 98, 100, 200, 300 }
```

Comment: Obvisouly you didnt read the comment in the code where I stated that the set is created somewhere else and I **cannot** create a new one

Comment: Okay got. Mean to say you already have a **Set** created and you want to add all values of any to that? Let me update my code and let you know. Thanks for reminding my mistake.

Comment: **@Fuzzyma**, I think you should define one method on **Set** using prototyping feature of JavaScript. Make sure to not use the in-built method names defined on **Set**. I have updated my answer with little example. Please check it let me know your suggestion.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180). Also, your answer (and comments) would be more readable if you used less formatting. Finally, Stack Overflow has a feature called Stack Snippets. In the editor you can click the button with angle brackets (`<>`) and paste your JavaScript code into it. That will make it runnable for others.

Comment: **@Mike**, I have already mentioned this in my code even I have not used it. Actually I am using mobile phone so I'm unable to see  JS editor here. Thanks.