# How can I efficiently compare each value in an array with each other value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array called `entriesFinal` that contains arrays with a **start time**, **end time**, and **duration**.

I want to push these entries to an empty array called `ganttData`, adding on a couple of extra fields.

Some of the entries in `entriesFinal` overlap, and I don't want these in `ganttData`.

Below is my current implementation which is **functionally perfect**, but the **execution time is too long**.

N.B. `forEachAsync` is a custom method that is functionally equivalent to a regular `forEach`, but works asynchronously.

```
let invalidEntries = []

await forEachAsync(entriesFinal, async entry1 => {
    await forEachAsync(entriesFinal, async entry2 => {

        if(entry1 != entry2){
            let invalidStart = entry2.startTime.isBetween(entry1.startTime, entry1.endTime)
            let invalidEnd= entry2.endTime.isBetween(entry1.startTime, entry1.endTime)
            if(invalidStart || invalidEnd){
                invalidEntries.push(entry2)
            }
        }   

    })  
})

await forEachAsync(entriesFinal, async entry => {

    if(!invalidEntries.includes(entry)){
        ganttData.push({
            name: channel.name,
            label: label,
            startTime: entry.startTime.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
            endTime: entry.endTime.format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
            duration: entry.duration
        })
    }

})
```

Is there a more efficient way of excluding the overlapping entries? This whole sequence is inside a wider loop which runs ~1500 times, hence my need to minimize the execution time of this process.

Comment: did you compare the time with regular `for(;;)` loop? function calls have pretty big overhead depending on the browser optimizations

Comment: if you sort entries by startTime, you'll only need to compare an entry with the previous one, not with all others.

Comment: @Slai are you talking about the isBetween() function? If so, I am using moment.js for the dates and isBetween() is a built-in function

Comment: functions in general have more overhead than native JavaScript, but my guess is  that the custom forEachAsync has even more overhead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821759/why-array-foreach-is-slower-than-for-loop-in-javascript