# How to remove certain values from an array object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove `__v` in every array element. How can I iterate through this array while removing the `__v` value from each element?

This is how my array looks like:

```
    [
    {
        "itemName": "SDGSGEDEDW",
        "description": "No description found",
        "_id": "5d97e155976e7e145476298b",
        "itemCode": "JFDQEKDEDQCGD",
        "untiPrice": 23.23,
        "vendor": "5d97e97177882e5b886fe32a",
        "dateAdded": "2019-10-05T00:18:29.128Z",
        "__v": 0 //want to remove this
    },
    {
        "itemName": "SDGSGEDEDW",
        "description": "No description found",
        "_id": "5d97e2e7d7a4b12dd800bca6",
        "itemCode": "JFDQEKDEDQCGD",
        "untiPrice": 23.23,
        "vendor": "5d97ea3177882e5b886fe330",
        "dateAdded": "2019-10-05T00:25:11.665Z",
        "__v": 0 //want to remove this
    }
]
```

So after removing the final array would should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "itemName": "SDGSGEDEDW",
        "description": "No description found",
        "_id": "5d97e155976e7e145476298b",
        "itemCode": "JFDQEKDEDQCGD",
        "untiPrice": 23.23,
        "vendor": "5d97e97177882e5b886fe32a",
        "dateAdded": "2019-10-05T00:18:29.128Z"
    },
    {
        "itemName": "SDGSGEDEDW",
        "description": "No description found",
        "_id": "5d97e2e7d7a4b12dd800bca6",
        "itemCode": "JFDQEKDEDQCGD",
        "untiPrice": 23.23,
        "vendor": "5d97ea3177882e5b886fe330",
        "dateAdded": "2019-10-05T00:25:11.665Z"
    }
]
```

Here what I was trying but it is not working:

```
arr.filter((item) => {
          return item.__v !== 0
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do that `arr.forEach((item) => delete item.__v);`

Comment: what is `delete` exactly? is it a predefined function?

Comment: Here you can read the answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it

```
arr.forEach(function(item){
  delete item['__v'];
});
```

Also - if performance matters for your application - using a `for` loop would be better than `forEach`.  [Heres a bit more on why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821759/why-array-foreach-is-slower-than-for-loop-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you and how can I delete another value?  should I add another delete statement?

Comment: Yep.  `delete` what you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `Destructuring assignment`

```html
const arr = [
    {
        "itemName": "SDGSGEDEDW",
        "description": "No description found",
        "_id": "5d97e155976e7e145476298b",
        "itemCode": "JFDQEKDEDQCGD",
        "untiPrice": 23.23,
        "vendor": "5d97e97177882e5b886fe32a",
        "dateAdded": "2019-10-05T00:18:29.128Z",
        "__v": 0 //want to remove this
    },
    {
        "itemName": "SDGSGEDEDW",
        "description": "No description found",
        "_id": "5d97e2e7d7a4b12dd800bca6",
        "itemCode": "JFDQEKDEDQCGD",
        "untiPrice": 23.23,
        "vendor": "5d97ea3177882e5b886fe330",
        "dateAdded": "2019-10-05T00:25:11.665Z",
        "__v": 0 //want to remove this
    }
];

const res = arr.map(item => {
  const { __v, ...rest} = item;
  return rest;
});

console.log(res);
```