# Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, operators, post-increment, pre-increment

I read [Is there a performance difference between i++ and ++i in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c):

> Is there a performance difference between `i++` and `++i` if the resulting value is not used?

What's the answer for JavaScript?

For example, which of the following is better?

1. ```js
   for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
     // code
   }
   ```
2. ```js
   for (var i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
     // code
   }
   ```

Comment: Not enough to matter to you.  I tend to prefer the ++i notation unless it's explicitly wrong for the use case.

Comment: with any decent js engine it should be identical

Comment: i hear there's a jsperf.com but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Pretty sure this is trivial for _real_ performance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546981/post-increment-vs-pre-increment-javascript-optimization

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an article about this topic: http://jsperf.com/i-vs-i/2

`++i` seems to be *slightly* faster (I tested it on firefox) and one reason, according to the article, is:

> with i++, before you can increment i under the hood a new copy of i must be created. Using ++i you don't need that extra copy. i++ will return the current value before incrementing i. ++i returns the incremented version i.

Comment: This is really more of a comment. An answer would explain how that link answers the question.

Comment: @jasper i was coming to that :)

Comment: it depends on your browser. ++i is slower in safari but faster in some browsers.

Comment: "under the hood a new copy of i must be created" - only if you use the result...

Answer (score -5):

No. There is no difference in execution time. The difference in the two code snippets is when i gets incremented.

```
for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

This first example will yield the results: 0,1,2,3,...,max-1

```
for(i = 0; i < max; ++i)
{
    console.log(i);
}
```

This second example will yield the results: 1,2,3,...,max

i++ increments the value after the operation.
++i increments the value before the operation.

There is no performance difference other than the one less iteration it will make on ++i because the increment is done before the first operation

Comment: I'm not sure why the down-vote. The JSPerf linked-to in jidma's answer shows that the two perform the same.

Comment: Agreed, well within 1% of each other. ++i shows to be 1% slower in Safari 6.x.  A good example to explain the difference is `var i = 0; alert(++i);` vs `var i = 0; alert(i++);`

Comment: -1. Both codes print the same thing.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/oninoy/1/edit

Comment: DeveloperKlin: In a loop the assertion that you make about the value if `i` is invalid, it is however valid when taken in other contexts, like concocting a string.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i agree, in order to have different results it should be `for(i = 0; i < max; ) console.log(++i)` vs `for(i = 0; i < max; ) console.log(i++)`

Comment: @elclanrs here is what he meant http://jsbin.com/oninoy/2/edit

Comment: I checked out what you guys had said and it appears you are right. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yeah, in a loop statement it doesn't make a difference in the output because it gets evaluated after the iteration. You have to use it inside to see the difference like others said.

Comment: Is "console.log" slow enough to hide the difference between ++i and i++ ?

Comment: @Nateowami: Just wonder if it is meaningful to time a loop with irrelevant function calls that may be too slow than the thing to be measured (i++ or ++i). What if console is a slow serial port or punch card?

Comment: @Qi Fan Oh, I see what you were saying. My mistake. Just deleted it.