# Javascript - How does "++i" work?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iterator, console.log

After experimenting with the use of "i++" and "++i" I could not find a difference between their results when used in a 'for' loop.
For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

would yield:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Shouldn't it be printing out the numbers from 1 to 10, as the iterator is being incremented before `console.log(i)` executes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pre increment in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930661/pre-increment-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "increment step" is executed **after** the loop body is executed. Given

```
for (a;b;c) {
  d
}
```

the execution order is

```
a // initialize
b // condition - first iteration
d // loop body
c // "increment"
b // condition - second iteration
d // loop body
c // "increment"
...
b // condition - last iteration - break
```

So in your case:

```
var i = 0;
i < 10;
console.log(i); // 0
++i;
i < 10;
console.log(i); // 1
++i;
// ...
i < 10;
```

The difference between `i++` and `++i` is only relevant if you do something with the return value, which you don't.

Comment: Good answer. Also, an interesting note... Assuming i++ and ++i in javascript work similarly to C, ++i as a means to simply increment (such as in your example) is slightly quicker. ++i increments the value right away, while i++ actually has to make a copy of its value to support post-increments.

Comment: @Jeff: Interesting. At least according to the ECMAScript specification there is not really a difference between those two: http://es5.github.io/#x11.3.1, http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.4. The steps are exactly the same safe for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Because the last clause of the `for` loop only happens at the end of the loop, as its own statement, the behavior of your loop is not affected by this difference. However, imagine you did something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10;) {
    console.log(++i);
}
for (var j = 0; j < 10;) {
    console.log(j++);
}
```

Then you'd see a difference. The first example would produce numbers 1-10, whereas the second would produce numbers 0-9. That's because `f(j++)` is equivalent to `j += 1; f(j);`, whereas `f(++i)` is more like `f(i); i += 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

May I advise that while your testing is fine on whatever platform you are using, the standard construct is i++

Always code the standard and isolate various platforms and make exceptions as needed !!!

i++ Simply means increment 'i' by one.

I can speculate ++i means to add 'i' to itself eg if 'i' was 2 then it would then increment to 2,4,8,16,32

But I have never seen ++i used in many places.

Comment: Both `i++` (post-increment) and `++i` (pre-increment) are pretty standard operations in C like languages. Granted, the latter is not as common, but it's still standard. `i++` means "increment `i` by one and return the old value of `i`". `++i` means "increment `i` by one and return the new value of `i`". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469885/somevariable-vs-somevariable-in-javascript