# Increment(i++) and (i+=1) in Javascript recursive call

Tags: javascript, recursion, increment

I have a question about JS increment(++). I know many people here asked about ++ and +1 difference in JS but none of them mentioned it in recursive call sentence.

**QUESTION:**
I want to call function exec inside exec function recursively but the flowing script is not working well.

```
var exec = function(index){
    if(index<7){
        exec(index++);
    }
}
exec(0);

output: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So I changed my script to the below and it worked well.

```
var exec = function(index){
    if(index<7){
        exec(index+=1);
    }
}
exec(0);
```

Why it acts like differenctly in this example? Is my recursive call wrong?

Comment: This looks like a question about postincrement vs preincrement `++i` vs `i++`. If you try `++i` it should work.

Comment: In this case you should probably just be using `i+1`

Comment: @raina77ow This question has nothing to do with optimization. That duplicate question is about which to use in loops for performance reasons.

Comment: Related questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318554/javascript-how-does-i-work), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930661/pre-increment-in-javascript), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript). Still not sure this one's better than the rest. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index++` is post-increment. That means it increments the variable, but the value of the expression is the *old* value. So:

```
exec(index++);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var oldindex = index;
index += 1;
exec(oldindex);
```

So the recursive call uses the old value, which means you keep calling recursively with the same value, and never hit the limit that stops recursing.

You need to use pre-increment, which increments the variable and returns the *new* value:

```
exec(++index);
```

Actually, there's no reason to increment the variable at all, since you never uses it again in that function. Just do:

```
exec(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `index++` is that it is a post-increment, so it only increments the value of `index` *after* it's already been passed back into `exec`. Using the pre-increment (`++index`) should work, since it will then increment it before passing it into the recursive call.

```js
var exec = function(index){
    console.log(index)
    if(index<7){
        exec(++index);
    }
}
exec(0);
```