# Basic operator: Why int z = x-- + 2*x = 25? What's the calculation process?

Tags: java, operators

I get stuck in the last expression,

shouldn't the calculation step for int `z = x-- + 2*x` be: `int z = (9) + 2(9)= 27`?

However, when I try to run it, the assignment to int z turns out to be 25, why?

Below is the expressions:

```
int x = 10;

int y = --x + x;

int z = x-- + 2*x;
```

And the result is:

```
[1] x = 10

[2] x = 9; y = 18

[3] x = 8; z = 25
```

Comment: `x--` is **post**-decrement operator. So, the value of the `x` will be used in expression first and then decrement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546981/post-increment-vs-pre-increment-javascript-optimization duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

At start

```
int x = 10;
```

when you run

```
int y = --x + x;
```

`x` got decremented by `-1` then `x` become `9` so `9+9 = 18`

in this line

```
int z = x-- + 2*x;
```

First x was `9` then got decremented by  `-1` then x become `8` so `9+8*2 = 25`

N:B

- pre `increment`/`decrements` execute first like `++x/--x`;
- post `increment`/`decrements` execute last like `x++/x--`

Comment: Very clear;D Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DummyMe you are welcome :)