# Why a value incremented in x while not in found object?

Tags: javascript

**Code**:

```
const x = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];
let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1);
if(found) found = {...found, a: found.a++};
console.log(x); // [{a: 2}, {b: 2}];
console.log(found) // {a: 1}
```

Why this code changed the value of **a** in **x** while not in **found object**??

Comment: because `found` is a reference to `x[0]` and you've increased the value of `x[0].a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets divide your question into two parts

> Why this code changed the value of a in x?

This is because `found` is refers to the object inside the array. So when you change the `a` prop of found `found.a++` it changes the object inside the array. Because `found === x[0]`

> Why value of `a` is not in `found` object?

This is are using the increment operator after the variable. So it sets `a` to previous value not the incremented value. You need to use `++` before variable.

```js
const x = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];
let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1);
if(found) found = {...found, a: ++found.a};
console.log(x); // [{a: 2}, {b: 2}];
console.log(found) // {a: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
found = {...found, a: found.a++}
```

...creates a new object.

You are using the [postfix increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators):

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), then it increments and returns the value before incrementing.

...so it increments `found.a` (and since `found` is a reference to `x[0]` it also increments `x[0].a`) but returns the value *before* incrementing...and this is the value used for the new object you are creating that then gets assigned to `found`.

If you want to also increment `found.a` you can use *prefix* which

> increments and returns the value after incrementing

...as can be seen here:

```js
const x = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];
let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1);
if(found) found = {...found, a: ++found.a};  // <= use prefix
console.log(x); // [{a: 2}, {b: 2}];
console.log(found) // {a: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why it appears on x ?

found is reference to the `{a: 1}` which  same as `x[0]`, so any change on `found` will refer to `x[0]` as well,

to prove this point you can see this

```js
const x = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];
let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1);

console.log(found === x[0])  // same reference
console.log(found === {a:1}) // different reference
```

> why doesn't appear of found  ?

You're using post increment which will first assign value  and then increment

If you need it to first increment value you can use pre-increment

```js
const x = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}];

let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1);
if (found) {
 found = { ...found,  a: ++found.a};
}
console.log(x);
console.log(found)
```

You can read it for further understanding of [`Pre-increment vs post-increment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546981/post-increment-vs-pre-increment-javascript-optimization)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const x = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  b: 2
}];
console.log(x); //original array
let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1); 
console.log(found);// fetch value from array which is similar as 1
if(found){
console.log(found)
found = { ...found,
  a: found.a++ //incremented value of element a with 1 so you get incremented value with new object (so you get the incremented value with new object)
}};
console.log(x); // [{a: 2}, {b: 2}];
console.log(found) // {a: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

`let found = x.find(el => el.a === 1)` returns the element of the array that matches the condition and declare that found is a reference to that object.
In the next assignment :

```
if(found) found = {...found, a: found.a++};
```

you are first manipulating (a: found.a++) the found variable by adding 1 to the found.a property (note that in this moment found points to the element returned by x.find())
After you did that, you declare that found now points to an object built with the {...found, a: found.a++} expression.

Note that, as you called a: found.a++, the found.a++ returns the value incremented where you place it, but only apply the changes to the original variable (found.a) in the next statement. That is why it doesn't propagate the change to the x value.