# Problem with Javascript Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript and writing the classic Rock Paper Scissors game and having one issue at the moment. The scores don't seem to update the first time both the player and computer win. Only the second time the player and computer win does the score add a point to the scoreboard. In other words, the points of either the computer or player are always 1 point behind. Appreciate the help in understanding why this is happening.

Here is my JS/HTML code:

```js
const totalChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    
    let rock_button = document.getElementById("rock");
    let paper_button = document.getElementById("paper");
    let scissors_button = document.getElementById("scissors");
    let resultNarrative = document.getElementById("resultNarrative");
    let userScorePath = document.getElementById("playerScore");
    let computerScorePath = document.getElementById("computerScore");
    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;
    
    const compareChoices = (player) => {
        let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        let computerChoice = totalChoices[randomNum];
        console.log(computerChoice);
        console.log(player);
        if (computerChoice === totalChoices[0]) {
            if (player === totalChoices[1]) {
                narrative(`The Player wins! The computer chose ${totalChoices[0]}  
                            and the player chose ${totalChoices[1]}`);
                playerPoint(playerScore++);
                console.log(playerScore);
            } else if (player === totalChoices[2]) {
                narrative(`The computer wins! The computer chose 
                            ${totalChoices[0]} and the player chose  ${totalChoices[2]}`);
    
                computerPoint(computerScore++);
                console.log(computerScore);
            }
        }
        if (computerChoice === totalChoices[1]) {
            if (player === totalChoices[2]) {
                narrative(`The Player wins! The computer chose ${totalChoices[1]} 
                            and the player chose ${totalChoices[2]}`);
                playerPoint(playerScore++);
                console.log(playerScore);
            } else if (player === totalChoices[0]) {
                narrative(`The computer wins! The computer chose ${totalChoices[1]} and the player chose ${totalChoices[0]}`);
                computerPoint(computerScore++);
                console.log(computerScore);
            }
        }
        if (computerChoice === totalChoices[2]) {
            if (player === totalChoices[0]) {
                narrative(`The Player wins! The computer chose 
                               ${totalChoices[2]} and the player chose  ${totalChoices[0]}`);
                playerPoint(playerScore++);
                console.log(playerScore);
            } else if (player === totalChoices[1]) {
                narrative(`The computer wins! The computer chose 
                                ${totalChoices[2]} and the player chose  ${totalChoices[1]}`);
                computerPoint(computerScore++);
                console.log(computerScore);
            }
        }
        if (computerChoice === player) {
            narrative(`There is a tie! The computer chose ${computerChoice}  
                            and the player chose ${player}`);
        }
    };
    
    function main() {
        rock_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            player = compareChoices("rock");
            console.log("you chose Rock");
        });
        paper_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            player = compareChoices("paper");
            console.log("you chose Paper");
        });
        scissors_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            player = compareChoices("scissors");
            console.log("you chose Scissors");
        });
    }
    
    main();
    
    function playerPoint(point) {
        userScorePath.innerHTML = point;
        console.log(point);
    }
    
    function computerPoint(point) {
        computerScorePath.innerHTML = point;
        console.log(point);
    }
    
    let narrative = (result) => {
        resultNarrative.innerHTML = result;
    };
    
    document.getElementById("rockPic").addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("You chose the rock image");
    });
    
    document.getElementById("paperPic").addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("You chose the paper image");
    });
    
    document.getElementById("scissorsPic").addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("You chose the scissors image");
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RPS_Style.css">
<title>Rock Paper Scissor Game</title>
<h1>Welcome to the Classic Game of Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scoreboard">
    <span class = "score" id="playerScoreLabel">Player Score</span> : 
<span id="playerScore">0</span>
    <br>
    <span class = "score" id="computerScoreLabel">Computer 
Score</span> : <span id="computerScore">0</span>
    
    
</div>     
<h2>Ready to Test Your Luck? Choose an option below!</h2>
<div class="choices">
    <button id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="paper">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>

    <div class="images">
        <img src="Rock Image.png" id = "rockPic" alt="picture of 
rock"/>
        <img src="Paper Image.png" id = "paperPic" alt="picture of 
 paper"/>
        <img src="Scissors Image.png" id = "scissorsPic" alt="picture 
of scissors"/>
    </div>

    <p id="resultNarrative">The player chose rock and the computer 
chose scissors. Player wins!</p>

</div>
<script src="AppRockPaperScissor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I tried to format the code, the JavaScript was missing close braces. That's the first thing you need to fix, since this code won't even run.

Answer (score 1):

`playerPoint(playerScore++)` passes the *current* value of `playerScore` to the `playerPoint()` function, then increments it afterwards. You want to increment the value *before* passing it to `playerPoint()`:

```
playerPoint(++playerScore)
```

Same thing for the `computerPoint()` function.

[post increment vs pre increment - Javascript Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546981/post-increment-vs-pre-increment-javascript-optimization)

Comment: Thanks. That works! However, just confused on why my console.log of say playerScore++ shows the correct number at say 1 and that is essentially what I think I am passing into my function of playerPoint in the line right above but it's passing in 0 apparently. I would think at the comparision where I say playerScore ++it would take the variable I set outside the function of playerScore = 0 and when I say playerScore ++ it would just increment that by 1 and pass to the playerPoint function and ultimately display in the HTML as 1. What am I missing? Just trying to understand how JS processes that

Comment: @ShaunValentine You're not calling `console.log(playerScore++)`. I see `console.log(playerScore)`, which will log the current value of `playerScore`. When you call `playerPoint(playerScore++)`, it passes the *current value* of `playerScore`, then increments the value of `playerScore` afterwards. When you subsequently call `console.log(playerScore)`, you will get the new (subsequently incremented) value.

Answer (score 0):

Taking base on @kmoser answer the code should be like this.
Ps: I also edited your code to fix some formats the concatenation were done wrongly I used [templatestrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead

```js
const totalChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

let rock_button = document.getElementById("rock");
let paper_button = document.getElementById("paper");
let scissors_button = document.getElementById("scissors");
let resultNarrative = document.getElementById("resultNarrative");
let userScorePath = document.getElementById("playerScore");
let computerScorePath = document.getElementById("computerScore");
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

const compareChoices = (player) => {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let computerChoice = totalChoices[randomNum];
    console.log(computerChoice);
    console.log(player);
    if (computerChoice === totalChoices[0]) {
        if (player === totalChoices[1]) {
            narrative(`The Player wins! The computer chose ${totalChoices[0]}  
                        and the player chose ${totalChoices[1]}`);
            playerPoint(++playerScore);
            console.log(playerScore);
        } else if (player === totalChoices[2]) {
            narrative(`The computer wins! The computer chose 
                        ${totalChoices[0]} and the player chose  ${totalChoices[2]}`);

            computerPoint(++computerScore);
            console.log(computerScore);
        }
    }
    if (computerChoice === totalChoices[1]) {
        if (player === totalChoices[2]) {
            narrative(`The Player wins! The computer chose ${totalChoices[1]} 
                        and the player chose ${totalChoices[2]}`);
            playerPoint(++playerScore);
            console.log(playerScore);
        } else if (player === totalChoices[0]) {
            narrative(`The computer wins! The computer chose ${totalChoices[1]} and the player chose ${totalChoices[0]}`);
            computerPoint(++computerScore);
            console.log(computerScore);
        }
    }
    if (computerChoice === totalChoices[2]) {
        if (player === totalChoices[0]) {
            narrative(`The Player wins! The computer chose 
                           ${totalChoices[2]} and the player chose  ${totalChoices[0]}`);
            playerPoint(++playerScore);
            console.log(playerScore);
        } else if (player === totalChoices[1]) {
            narrative(`The computer wins! The computer chose 
                            ${totalChoices[2]} and the player chose  ${totalChoices[1]}`);
            computerPoint(++computerScore);
            console.log(computerScore);
        }
    }
    if (computerChoice === player) {
        narrative(`There is a tie! The computer chose ${computerChoice}  
                        and the player chose ${player}`);
    }
};

function main() {
    rock_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        player = compareChoices("rock");
        console.log("you chose Rock");
    });
    paper_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        player = compareChoices("paper");
        console.log("you chose Paper");
    });
    scissors_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        player = compareChoices("scissors");
        console.log("you chose Scissors");
    });
}

main();

function playerPoint(point) {
    userScorePath.innerHTML = point;
    console.log(point);
}

function computerPoint(point) {
    computerScorePath.innerHTML = point;
    console.log(point);
}

let narrative = (result) => {
    resultNarrative.innerHTML = result;
};

document.getElementById("rockPic").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("You chose the rock image");
});

document.getElementById("paperPic").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("You chose the paper image");
});

document.getElementById("scissorsPic").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("You chose the scissors image");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RPS_Style.css">
<title>Rock Paper Scissor Game</title>
<h1>Welcome to the Classic Game of Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scoreboard">
    <span class = "score" id="playerScoreLabel">Player Score</span> : 
<span id="playerScore">0</span>
    <br>
    <span class = "score" id="computerScoreLabel">Computer 
Score</span> : <span id="computerScore">0</span>
    
    
</div>     
<h2>Ready to Test Your Luck? Choose an option below!</h2>
<div class="choices">
    <button id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="paper">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>

    <div class="images">
        <img src="Rock Image.png" id = "rockPic" alt="picture of 
rock"/>
        <img src="Paper Image.png" id = "paperPic" alt="picture of 
 paper"/>
        <img src="Scissors Image.png" id = "scissorsPic" alt="picture 
of scissors"/>
    </div>

    <p id="resultNarrative">The player chose rock and the computer 
chose scissors. Player wins!</p>

</div>
<script src="AppRockPaperScissor.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```